# iOS Dev: Why does self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height return zero?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a modal popup view with a nav bar and when I try to access the height of that nav bar from the currently loaded view using the statement...

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
```

...it returns 0.  Why would that be?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: what format argument are you using (ie %@, %llu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because one of the object you are using in your expression is `nil`.

This is probably the `self.navigationController` itself for example. Maybe you misinterpreted your view hierarchy? (Try to `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);` to check if it is `nil` or not and be sure)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but if you didn't change anything, a nav bar will always have a 44 pixels height

Comment: That is not true. In Landscape more on iPhone, the NavigationBar is not the same height as in Portrait mode.

Comment: True, sorry it's 32 for landscape

Comment: And besides, it's bad practice to use magic numbers in your code, like hard-written values. We's seen that Apple can change stuff in the OS and in the phone itself (e.g. everybody that hard-wroted `480` ad the height of the screen in their code are screwed today, whereas using `view.window.screen.applicationFrame.size.height` still return the right value everywhere), so nothing guaranties that Apple won't change the height of the NavBar in a future version of iOS for example. It is thus a better practice to get the value like the OP tried instead of hard-coding the value.

Comment: :) Ok you're right... But it still good to know those values if you want to change the appearance :) (not related here but still !)